# Old value not setting properly on laravel 9 blade dropdown

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel application I have a simple form with a dropdown.

Dropdown options are getting filled with DB data.

I want to populate my dropdown with user previously selected option on the edit.

Following is what I have done so far..

Blade

```
<select name="company_id" class="form-control">
                            @foreach($companies as $company)
                                @if (old('company_id') == $employee->company_id)
                                    <option value="{{ $company->id }}" selected>{{ $company->name }}</option>
                                @else
                                    <option value="{{ $company->id }}">{{ $company->name }}</option>
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
```

Controller.

```
public function edit(Employee $employee)
    {
        $companies = Company::all(['id','name']);
        return view('employees.edit', compact('employee','companies'));
    }
```

Employee Model

```
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone', 'company_id'
    ];

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }
}
```

My company table structure

[image]

Employee table structure

[image]

When I tried with these, it kept showing me the values in the dropdown on the edit but not setting the old value properly.....

Comment: why `$employee->company_id` in your blade foreach loop? It should be `$company->id`.

Comment: still the old value is not setting....

Comment: Also In first reload it doesn't pass the If-statement, because old value become null. To pass the if -statement you have to submit form at first. Also else-statement you didn't add selected attribute, so you may sound not working.

Comment: `old` is used to show the previous form values that a user selected when they submitted the form and a form validation error occured. It is not used to show the current values from the database. That's completely different logic

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 9 you don't have to use `if-else` to check the value just use the [`@selected()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#additional-attributes) blade function/directive.

```
<select name="company_id" class="form-control">
    @foreach($companies as $company)
        <option value="{{ $company->id }}" @selected(old('company_id') == $company->id)>{{ $company->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Also, we have the `@checked()` function as well:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="active" value="active" @checked(old('active', $user->active)) />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your loop:

```
@foreach ($companies as $company)
    <option value="{{ $company->id }}" {{ $company->id == old('company_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}>
         {{ $company->name_en }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be `typecasting`.

```
@if (old('company_id') === $employee->company_id)
```

This will never be true. You see `old` holds string values and you're comparing it against an id which is of type `int`.
So, this will work for you:

```
@if ( (int)old('company_id') === $employee->company_id )
```

Also, there is a new directive you can use instead of conventional if-else statements `checked` :

```
@checked( old('key', $employee->key) )
@selected( old('key') === $employee->key )
```